# Is there a way to pay for apps with paypal?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

Is there a market where I can buy apps with PayPal?
Will the original Market going to support payment with PayPal?

Thanx.

Comment: No official support, rumor and speculation: http://androidandme.com/2010/12/news/what-happened-to-paypal-payments-in-the-android-market/

Answer (score 5):

With the recent legal bickering between eBay and Google, I'd say that the Android Market starting to accept PayPal (owned by eBay) is highly unlikely any time soon:
 http://www.csmonitor.com/Business/Latest-News-Wires/2011/0528/EBay-sues-Google-over-stolen-secrets-poached-employees

There are other alternative markets like [SlideMe](http://slideme.org/) that I believe do offer PayPal.

Comment: Amazon is a competitor of eBay and definitely does not use PayPal.

Comment: True, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Neither Google Android Market nor the Amazon Appstore support Paypal.

[SlideMe.org](http://slideme.org/) is an alternative market which does [support Paypal payments](http://slideme.org/payments). It's not a mirror, so you won't find as many apps as you would in the official Google Market.

Answer (score 5):

[YAAM](http://yaam.mobi) (Yet Another Android Market) uses PayPal, I've had no problems with it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official support for Paypal in the android market, and seeing how Google and Paypal now seem to be competing a bit, I doubt there ever will be. But, if you want to use Paypal, you may be able to sign up for the [Paypal Debit card](https://personal.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/debit_card) and link that to your Google Checkout account. Then you will be using Paypal to make your purchases, and you can earn %1 cash back on the purchase.

Comment: Good option, need to mention that Paypal Debit card is available only in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows Play Store apps to be purchased using PayPal (starting from May 15, 2014):

> Starting today, we're making it possible for people to choose PayPal
>   for their Google Play purchases in 12 countries, including the U.S.,
>   Germany, and Canada. When you make a purchase on Google Play in these
>   countries, you'll find PayPal as an option in your Google Wallet; just
>   enter your PayPal account login and you'll easily be able to make
>   purchases.

Source:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/05/helping-you-go-global-with-more.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, you could get a debit card hooked to your paypal account. Both their straight debit card, and their prepaid debit card are master-card branded, so you can use them as your Google app store payment option.

It's not the app store taking Paypal, of course, but it gets you what you want without the players involved having to come to any agreements.

Comment: NOTE: These are debit cards, so you don't get CC protections!
I suggest one of two approaches:
1) Get the pre-paid Paypal debit card, and only push a little money to it when you want to buy something. The idea here is that a card number breach won't let the bad guys suck your Paypal account dry.

2) Get the regular Paypal debit card, and don't keep much money in the Paypal account or the bank account it's hooked to. This is slower to re-load, but again the idea is to not let the bad guys have any chance of sucking you dry if the card number is compromised.

Answer (score -1):

You can buy a gift card and use it yourself. I have used paypal to buy gift card from www.pcgamesupply.com and redeem it on google play.